# Variable automatically change in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have method which take interface parameter. But i want that my original parameter "selectItemList" not change. So, I create new constant "itemlist". And I added item to "itemList".But, when I added item to itemList, then automatically added to selectItemList. I want only change "itemList" not "
selectItemList". Where is my mistake?

SelectItem.ts (Interface)

```
export interface SelectItem {
    label?: string;
    value: any;
    styleClass?: string;
    icon?: string;
    title?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

My method

```
  addUnselectedItem(selectItemList: SelectItem[]): SelectItem[] {
    const itemList = selectItemList;
    itemList.unshift({ value: "", label: "Please Select" });
    return itemList;
  }
```

Comment: i hope this will help you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gp1t3t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @shubhamsingh. This answer also worked like Sarthak Aggarwal's answer.

Comment: hmm i know hence i m also upvote him .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making reference of 'selectItemList' in 'itemList'. You need to create new array to solve the above problem.

There are 2 methods to do the same.

1. copy all the elements in new array and then modify new array
2. use 'slice' method(returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array) of Array.

   `const itemList = selectItemList.slice(0,selectItemList.length);`